# Mirroring the look of a website in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter app, I want to show a website. As you know, websites have a mobile-friendly view. I want to show this view in application. For example, `stackoverflow.com`. I want to show the mobile view of `stackoverflow.com` on screen.

When I click on the text, the website will not open, as soon as the application is opened, the site I want will be displayed (reflected) in the application.

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean you want to see the website through your Flutter app as if it was like an iframe? Have you started something that you'd like to show us and help you debug?

Comment: @Roman Jaquez Yes, I want to display it like an iframe.

Comment: Use this flutter package: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a web view plugin, to embed a mobile version of any site on your flutter app.

You can look for this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview